# Sticky header slides down on scrolling up

Tags: javascript

This code working well: it's adding class gizle to the header then scrolling down and class sabit then scrolling up (also removing gizle). I need one little adjustment to this code: remove class sabit then scrolling reaches very top of the page. Is it possible?

html:

```
<header class="top">STICKY HEADER</header>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){   
var cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop();
var header_yuksekligi = $('.top').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var kaydirma_cubugu = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (kaydirma_cubugu > header_yuksekligi){$('.top').addClass('gizle');} 
    else {$('.top').removeClass('gizle');}

    if (kaydirma_cubugu > cubuk_seviye){$('.top').removeClass('sabit');} 
    else {$('.top').addClass('sabit');}             

    cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop(); 
 });
});
```

CSS:

```
.top{
background-color:#e74c3c; 
color:white; 
font-size:24px; 
padding:5px; 
text-align:center; 
position: fixed; 
left:0; 
top:0; 
width:100%; 
transition: top .5s;
}

.gizle {
top: -120px;
}
.sabit {
top:0;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your CSS as well?

Comment: whole code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/fwmsk0kb/)

Comment: What should happen with the Header while scrolling ? Should it just stay fixed ?

Comment: You just need to remove the line  : else {$('.top').addClass('sabit');}

Comment: @Ruby: then it doesn't slide down on scrolling up at all

Comment: @Gallex When it goes to the top, It slides down. Isn't that your requirement?

Comment: @DomeTune: my goal actually is to give background-color:red to class sabit. when user starts to scroll up header slides down and background color appears to the header, and then scrolling reaches to very top, background color disappears (code removes class sabit)

Comment: than you just need to add `.sabit { background: #e74c3c; color: white; }` and remove it from `.top`

Comment: @DomeTune: yes, but that's not the issue here. Issue is: than scrolling reaches at the very top of the page (i repeat:only at the top!), background color should disapper. this happens only, when code removes class sabit at the top. i corrected my jsfiddle CSS for better understanding

Comment: mh okey, than add another class with the background and remove this when `kaydirma_cubugu == 0`, [Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/DomeTune/fwmsk0kb/3/)

Comment: DomeTune, we are almost there! ;) one little thing i noticed: if you start scrolling down, the header with red bakground appears for a millisecond - could you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this address your issue?

```js
$(function(){ 
    var cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop();
    var header_yuksekligi = $('.top').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var kaydirma_cubugu = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (kaydirma_cubugu > header_yuksekligi){$('.top').addClass('gizle');} 
        else {$('.top').removeClass('gizle');}

        if (kaydirma_cubugu > cubuk_seviye){$('.top').removeClass('sabit');} 
        else {$('.top').addClass('sabit');}
        
        if (kaydirma_cubugu == 0) $('.top').removeClass('sabit');

        cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop(); 
     });
});
```

```css
body{background-color:white; padding-top:10px; font:100 14px 'Open Sans'}

#lipsum{width:690px; margin:30px auto; color:#34495e;text-align:justify}

img{float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}

.top{
  font-size:24px; 
  padding:5px; 
  text-align:center; 
  position: fixed; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  width:100%; 
  transition: top .5s;
}

.gizle {
  top: -120px;
}
.sabit {
   background-color:#e74c3c; 
  color:white; 
  top:0;
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="top">STICKY HEADER</header>
<div id="lipsum">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tempus ante augue, ultrices semper tellus eleifend eu. Integer eu arcu risus. Nam lobortis lectus aliquam lorem accumsan, nec blandit purus ultrices. Mauris consectetur ante vitae lacinia dapibus. Cras at eleifend ligula, ut ullamcorper ipsum. Vestibulum vestibulum mollis nisi consectetur elementum. Donec vel fermentum sapien. Etiam quis purus eu ante bibendum congue. Morbi pellentesque magna ac lacinia bibendum.
</p>
<p>
Duis vel faucibus purus. Nam interdum erat at bibendum tincidunt. Integer tempor hendrerit purus, sit amet fringilla felis imperdiet tempus. Nullam a sem eget velit mattis luctus at nec metus. Integer auctor viverra nulla, sit amet blandit nulla. Duis auctor est vitae turpis tincidunt, sit amet dictum purus cursus. Mauris venenatis lectus nec magna eleifend euismod.
</p>
<img src="http://www.adobewordpress.com/ads/300x250.jpg">
<p>
Morbi varius faucibus nulla ut pharetra. Vestibulum sed sapien turpis. Sed diam felis, ullamcorper vel augue id, porta porta nibh. Mauris interdum elit ac metus fermentum, eu porttitor purus venenatis. In nec metus vitae augue mattis porta in at erat. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus accumsan porta massa, eu scelerisque erat lacinia ac. Etiam feugiat mollis nisl, nec dignissim mauris fermentum nec. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor nec purus egestas fermentum. Etiam et imperdiet sem. Vestibulum in risus massa.
</p>
<p>
Mauris eleifend elit id purus vulputate aliquam. Suspendisse semper elit id diam malesuada sagittis. Quisque non nunc tempor, convallis felis at, placerat elit. Quisque quis nulla dapibus, vulputate diam id, dapibus sapien. Vestibulum commodo arcu at erat imperdiet ornare. Nulla vestibulum dolor sed mauris varius interdum. Quisque convallis, felis eu pharetra elementum, nisl velit consectetur nunc, eu dapibus elit ante eleifend ligula. Mauris elementum id velit ut ornare. Suspendisse a eros quis nunc sagittis tristique et id urna. Integer consequat odio quis nisl viverra gravida. Nulla interdum faucibus nunc, ac accumsan est. Duis non semper mi. Ut id semper ante, id pharetra mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus ut magna iaculis, pretium enim quis, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque ac dui aliquet nulla aliquam tempor quis sed dui.
</p>
<p>
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam quis ultrices ligula. Donec feugiat vitae sem et lacinia. Morbi eleifend, orci eu ornare tempor, nisl libero aliquet tortor, et varius massa dui semper ipsum. Vivamus vitae tortor lacus. Nulla tincidunt et neque ac mattis. Suspendisse lacus arcu, commodo vitae hendrerit porta, eleifend sollicitudin turpis.
</p>
<p>
Fusce tincidunt non libero et sagittis. Nunc luctus dui id sapien auctor vehicula. Quisque feugiat dui nec neque ullamcorper, eu ultricies velit vehicula. Aliquam iaculis consequat magna, vel feugiat lorem convallis sit amet. Pellentesque bibendum feugiat leo, in tristique sem vehicula quis. Nulla laoreet risus sapien, non pretium metus auctor sed. Etiam sed mattis dolor. Aenean eu tincidunt massa, et ultrices risus. Ut venenatis neque nec dui commodo tincidunt. Sed pellentesque hendrerit tortor ut fringilla. Ut ultricies tincidunt vulputate.
</p>
<p>
Nam sit amet lacus tincidunt, molestie dui dapibus, viverra diam. Donec fermentum ornare magna, in tincidunt turpis commodo in. Phasellus commodo et nunc congue laoreet. In ultricies suscipit diam quis suscipit. Donec nisl purus, ultricies in tellus quis, scelerisque laoreet dui. Nunc sollicitudin interdum metus. Ut eu nisl ac urna suscipit imperdiet. Donec cursus, eros et sollicitudin luctus, sem enim gravida sem, ac dignissim purus elit sed ipsum. Donec lobortis sapien nunc, quis interdum ante sagittis ut. Vestibulum vel placerat elit, non mollis est. Suspendisse nulla leo, fringilla vel scelerisque id, vulputate eu nisi. Morbi nec fermentum ligula, ac mollis metus. Morbi a felis diam. Duis eu lacinia magna. Curabitur auctor lectus ac leo ultrices, non interdum sem pharetra.
</p>
<p>
Etiam sagittis volutpat mi a pellentesque. Vestibulum et justo vitae nibh suscipit condimentum sit amet quis felis. Curabitur sed orci dui. Nulla ut faucibus ligula. Quisque id laoreet metus. Maecenas egestas odio a lectus tincidunt, quis rutrum eros venenatis. Praesent et urna dignissim, tincidunt augue eget, pharetra tortor. Curabitur ac turpis eros. Aenean nec lacus ut odio faucibus cursus condimentum eu magna. Nunc quis justo vitae sapien aliquam imperdiet.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam ornare, odio vitae luctus cursus, ante quam commodo dui, ac vulputate justo sapien sed mauris. Nulla malesuada commodo odio eu vulputate. Quisque ac ullamcorper diam, non interdum neque. Aliquam id enim auctor, imperdiet turpis sit amet, laoreet eros. Etiam eu lectus vitae lacus mattis semper eu luctus dolor. Aenean velit neque, convallis ut lorem vel, suscipit ultricies elit. Phasellus vel lorem vitae ante varius consequat. Curabitur adipiscing feugiat purus, at gravida nibh cursus vel. Ut purus ante, ultricies ac ultricies non, tempus ac tellus. Etiam id est eget magna tincidunt blandit. Maecenas volutpat, libero eget rhoncus congue, ipsum erat tempus turpis, vel gravida lorem urna eu nisl. Suspendisse eu enim in orci fringilla convallis. Ut sit amet nunc quis justo malesuada scelerisque. Vestibulum quis faucibus risus, eu rutrum lacus. In blandit rhoncus tempus. Nullam aliquet elit aliquam eleifend suscipit.
</p>
<p>
Vivamus nec sem eget mi rhoncus cursus. Nullam nisi elit, dictum quis eros id, adipiscing eleifend massa. Curabitur odio sem, pulvinar ac nunc quis, hendrerit dapibus nulla. Quisque luctus accumsan turpis ut scelerisque. Praesent urna sem, sollicitudin a vehicula eget, aliquam nec nisl. Maecenas ac blandit nisl. Integer fermentum feugiat ligula, ultrices feugiat ipsum pulvinar eu. Cras at faucibus nulla, non imperdiet odio. Fusce lacinia ipsum consectetur, luctus elit quis, semper tortor. Pellentesque a auctor diam. Vestibulum at consequat eros, at mollis massa. Pellentesque eleifend dignissim laoreet. Mauris sit amet nisi ac metus laoreet aliquet nec et risus. Cras malesuada neque non tincidunt ultricies. Quisque vitae enim condimentum, molestie tortor semper, tempor nisi.
</p>
<p>
Quisque et lectus vel mi interdum interdum eget quis ipsum. Etiam vel aliquam urna. Quisque pharetra convallis commodo. Curabitur fringilla diam non laoreet consectetur. Quisque malesuada nibh sed nisl porta vulputate. Ut est nisl, convallis non consectetur a, ultricies vel diam. Curabitur posuere, ipsum viverra fermentum bibendum, diam tellus facilisis justo, eget feugiat tortor elit vel dui. Morbi ultricies urna ut felis porttitor adipiscing in fermentum lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis luctus elementum ligula ut luctus. Mauris commodo ligula dapibus, gravida mauris et, eleifend augue. Nam vulputate eros eget scelerisque molestie.
</p>
<p>
Proin pulvinar arcu hendrerit odio imperdiet mattis. Mauris eget libero eget velit sodales laoreet. Nulla quis euismod libero. Ut ante dolor, semper in sapien id, posuere suscipit risus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla nec nunc commodo, consequat risus id, tempor urna. Quisque vehicula enim nec blandit euismod. Phasellus aliquam augue id consectetur placerat. Cras orci massa, aliquet vel leo eu, feugiat ultrices turpis. Pellentesque et molestie nulla. Praesent vehicula a enim eu tristique. Ut tempus ultricies quam, id iaculis lectus gravida ac. Ut gravida diam nisi, non tincidunt dui ultricies et. Integer sed fringilla augue, id condimentum diam.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus a ante felis. Nunc eget consequat nisl. Aliquam dapibus ornare mi, eu porttitor felis vestibulum at. Etiam bibendum id lectus quis luctus. Mauris semper et turpis rutrum ullamcorper. Mauris hendrerit malesuada porttitor. Proin et consectetur augue, sagittis placerat dui.
</p>
<p>
Fusce non turpis nec libero cursus posuere vel in erat. Nullam malesuada placerat magna et viverra. Praesent eu lorem lacus. Fusce nunc orci, feugiat ac pretium nec, vestibulum vel elit. Morbi a nibh orci. Nulla ac arcu egestas, sollicitudin est sit amet, ornare tellus. Mauris aliquam nec orci ac eleifend. Aliquam et lacus semper massa consequat fermentum. Proin neque nisi, blandit euismod velit et, dignissim varius mi. Nam porta interdum metus, eu sollicitudin erat ullamcorper sed. Aliquam erat volutpat.
</p>
<p>
Proin eget odio ultrices, sagittis sem ac, dictum nisl. Aenean bibendum id augue sodales lacinia. Morbi vehicula tincidunt tortor ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam elementum sem at dignissim hendrerit. Aenean dignissim neque urna, quis placerat mi viverra ut. Sed ultrices diam nec risus scelerisque, et consectetur sem laoreet. Suspendisse vitae odio purus. Aenean consectetur lacus vitae massa malesuada, sed interdum enim malesuada. Nulla pellentesque nunc ac dui condimentum interdum.
</p></div>
```

Comment: brilliant! exactly what i ment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var kaydirma_cubugu = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (kaydirma_cubugu > header_yuksekligi){$('.top').addClass('gizle');} 
        else {$('.top').removeClass('gizle');}

        if (kaydirma_cubugu > cubuk_seviye){$('.top').removeClass('sabit');} 
        else {$('.top').addClass('sabit');}     

        console.log($("body").scrollTop());

        if($(document).scrollTop() == 0)
        $('.top').removeClass('sabit');

        cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop(); 
     });
});
```

fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/saxf9wdm/

```js
$(function(){ 
    var cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop();
    var header_yuksekligi = $('.top').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var kaydirma_cubugu = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (kaydirma_cubugu > header_yuksekligi){$('.top').addClass('gizle');} 
        else {$('.top').removeClass('gizle');}

        if (kaydirma_cubugu > cubuk_seviye){$('.top').removeClass('sabit');} 
        else {$('.top').addClass('sabit');}  
       
        
        if($(document).scrollTop() == 0)
        $('.top').removeClass('sabit');

        cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop(); 
     });
});
```

```css
body{background-color:white; padding-top:10px; font:100 14px 'Open Sans'}

#lipsum{width:690px; margin:30px auto; color:#34495e;text-align:justify}

img{float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}

.top{
  color:black; 
  font-size:24px; 
  padding:5px; 
  text-align:center; 
  position: fixed; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  width:100%; 
  transition: top .5s;
}

.gizle {
  top: -120px;
}
.sabit {
  top:0;
 z-index: 9999;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="top">STICKY HEADER</header>
<div id="lipsum">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tempus ante augue, ultrices semper tellus eleifend eu. Integer eu arcu risus. Nam lobortis lectus aliquam lorem accumsan, nec blandit purus ultrices. Mauris consectetur ante vitae lacinia dapibus. Cras at eleifend ligula, ut ullamcorper ipsum. Vestibulum vestibulum mollis nisi consectetur elementum. Donec vel fermentum sapien. Etiam quis purus eu ante bibendum congue. Morbi pellentesque magna ac lacinia bibendum.
</p>
<p>
Duis vel faucibus purus. Nam interdum erat at bibendum tincidunt. Integer tempor hendrerit purus, sit amet fringilla felis imperdiet tempus. Nullam a sem eget velit mattis luctus at nec metus. Integer auctor viverra nulla, sit amet blandit nulla. Duis auctor est vitae turpis tincidunt, sit amet dictum purus cursus. Mauris venenatis lectus nec magna eleifend euismod.
</p>
<img src="http://www.adobewordpress.com/ads/300x250.jpg">
<p>
Morbi varius faucibus nulla ut pharetra. Vestibulum sed sapien turpis. Sed diam felis, ullamcorper vel augue id, porta porta nibh. Mauris interdum elit ac metus fermentum, eu porttitor purus venenatis. In nec metus vitae augue mattis porta in at erat. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus accumsan porta massa, eu scelerisque erat lacinia ac. Etiam feugiat mollis nisl, nec dignissim mauris fermentum nec. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor nec purus egestas fermentum. Etiam et imperdiet sem. Vestibulum in risus massa.
</p>
<p>
Mauris eleifend elit id purus vulputate aliquam. Suspendisse semper elit id diam malesuada sagittis. Quisque non nunc tempor, convallis felis at, placerat elit. Quisque quis nulla dapibus, vulputate diam id, dapibus sapien. Vestibulum commodo arcu at erat imperdiet ornare. Nulla vestibulum dolor sed mauris varius interdum. Quisque convallis, felis eu pharetra elementum, nisl velit consectetur nunc, eu dapibus elit ante eleifend ligula. Mauris elementum id velit ut ornare. Suspendisse a eros quis nunc sagittis tristique et id urna. Integer consequat odio quis nisl viverra gravida. Nulla interdum faucibus nunc, ac accumsan est. Duis non semper mi. Ut id semper ante, id pharetra mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus ut magna iaculis, pretium enim quis, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque ac dui aliquet nulla aliquam tempor quis sed dui.
</p>
<p>
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam quis ultrices ligula. Donec feugiat vitae sem et lacinia. Morbi eleifend, orci eu ornare tempor, nisl libero aliquet tortor, et varius massa dui semper ipsum. Vivamus vitae tortor lacus. Nulla tincidunt et neque ac mattis. Suspendisse lacus arcu, commodo vitae hendrerit porta, eleifend sollicitudin turpis.
</p>
<p>
Fusce tincidunt non libero et sagittis. Nunc luctus dui id sapien auctor vehicula. Quisque feugiat dui nec neque ullamcorper, eu ultricies velit vehicula. Aliquam iaculis consequat magna, vel feugiat lorem convallis sit amet. Pellentesque bibendum feugiat leo, in tristique sem vehicula quis. Nulla laoreet risus sapien, non pretium metus auctor sed. Etiam sed mattis dolor. Aenean eu tincidunt massa, et ultrices risus. Ut venenatis neque nec dui commodo tincidunt. Sed pellentesque hendrerit tortor ut fringilla. Ut ultricies tincidunt vulputate.
</p>
<p>
Nam sit amet lacus tincidunt, molestie dui dapibus, viverra diam. Donec fermentum ornare magna, in tincidunt turpis commodo in. Phasellus commodo et nunc congue laoreet. In ultricies suscipit diam quis suscipit. Donec nisl purus, ultricies in tellus quis, scelerisque laoreet dui. Nunc sollicitudin interdum metus. Ut eu nisl ac urna suscipit imperdiet. Donec cursus, eros et sollicitudin luctus, sem enim gravida sem, ac dignissim purus elit sed ipsum. Donec lobortis sapien nunc, quis interdum ante sagittis ut. Vestibulum vel placerat elit, non mollis est. Suspendisse nulla leo, fringilla vel scelerisque id, vulputate eu nisi. Morbi nec fermentum ligula, ac mollis metus. Morbi a felis diam. Duis eu lacinia magna. Curabitur auctor lectus ac leo ultrices, non interdum sem pharetra.
</p>
<p>
Etiam sagittis volutpat mi a pellentesque. Vestibulum et justo vitae nibh suscipit condimentum sit amet quis felis. Curabitur sed orci dui. Nulla ut faucibus ligula. Quisque id laoreet metus. Maecenas egestas odio a lectus tincidunt, quis rutrum eros venenatis. Praesent et urna dignissim, tincidunt augue eget, pharetra tortor. Curabitur ac turpis eros. Aenean nec lacus ut odio faucibus cursus condimentum eu magna. Nunc quis justo vitae sapien aliquam imperdiet.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam ornare, odio vitae luctus cursus, ante quam commodo dui, ac vulputate justo sapien sed mauris. Nulla malesuada commodo odio eu vulputate. Quisque ac ullamcorper diam, non interdum neque. Aliquam id enim auctor, imperdiet turpis sit amet, laoreet eros. Etiam eu lectus vitae lacus mattis semper eu luctus dolor. Aenean velit neque, convallis ut lorem vel, suscipit ultricies elit. Phasellus vel lorem vitae ante varius consequat. Curabitur adipiscing feugiat purus, at gravida nibh cursus vel. Ut purus ante, ultricies ac ultricies non, tempus ac tellus. Etiam id est eget magna tincidunt blandit. Maecenas volutpat, libero eget rhoncus congue, ipsum erat tempus turpis, vel gravida lorem urna eu nisl. Suspendisse eu enim in orci fringilla convallis. Ut sit amet nunc quis justo malesuada scelerisque. Vestibulum quis faucibus risus, eu rutrum lacus. In blandit rhoncus tempus. Nullam aliquet elit aliquam eleifend suscipit.
</p>
<p>
Vivamus nec sem eget mi rhoncus cursus. Nullam nisi elit, dictum quis eros id, adipiscing eleifend massa. Curabitur odio sem, pulvinar ac nunc quis, hendrerit dapibus nulla. Quisque luctus accumsan turpis ut scelerisque. Praesent urna sem, sollicitudin a vehicula eget, aliquam nec nisl. Maecenas ac blandit nisl. Integer fermentum feugiat ligula, ultrices feugiat ipsum pulvinar eu. Cras at faucibus nulla, non imperdiet odio. Fusce lacinia ipsum consectetur, luctus elit quis, semper tortor. Pellentesque a auctor diam. Vestibulum at consequat eros, at mollis massa. Pellentesque eleifend dignissim laoreet. Mauris sit amet nisi ac metus laoreet aliquet nec et risus. Cras malesuada neque non tincidunt ultricies. Quisque vitae enim condimentum, molestie tortor semper, tempor nisi.
</p>
<p>
Quisque et lectus vel mi interdum interdum eget quis ipsum. Etiam vel aliquam urna. Quisque pharetra convallis commodo. Curabitur fringilla diam non laoreet consectetur. Quisque malesuada nibh sed nisl porta vulputate. Ut est nisl, convallis non consectetur a, ultricies vel diam. Curabitur posuere, ipsum viverra fermentum bibendum, diam tellus facilisis justo, eget feugiat tortor elit vel dui. Morbi ultricies urna ut felis porttitor adipiscing in fermentum lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis luctus elementum ligula ut luctus. Mauris commodo ligula dapibus, gravida mauris et, eleifend augue. Nam vulputate eros eget scelerisque molestie.
</p>
<p>
Proin pulvinar arcu hendrerit odio imperdiet mattis. Mauris eget libero eget velit sodales laoreet. Nulla quis euismod libero. Ut ante dolor, semper in sapien id, posuere suscipit risus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla nec nunc commodo, consequat risus id, tempor urna. Quisque vehicula enim nec blandit euismod. Phasellus aliquam augue id consectetur placerat. Cras orci massa, aliquet vel leo eu, feugiat ultrices turpis. Pellentesque et molestie nulla. Praesent vehicula a enim eu tristique. Ut tempus ultricies quam, id iaculis lectus gravida ac. Ut gravida diam nisi, non tincidunt dui ultricies et. Integer sed fringilla augue, id condimentum diam.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus a ante felis. Nunc eget consequat nisl. Aliquam dapibus ornare mi, eu porttitor felis vestibulum at. Etiam bibendum id lectus quis luctus. Mauris semper et turpis rutrum ullamcorper. Mauris hendrerit malesuada porttitor. Proin et consectetur augue, sagittis placerat dui.
</p>
<p>
Fusce non turpis nec libero cursus posuere vel in erat. Nullam malesuada placerat magna et viverra. Praesent eu lorem lacus. Fusce nunc orci, feugiat ac pretium nec, vestibulum vel elit. Morbi a nibh orci. Nulla ac arcu egestas, sollicitudin est sit amet, ornare tellus. Mauris aliquam nec orci ac eleifend. Aliquam et lacus semper massa consequat fermentum. Proin neque nisi, blandit euismod velit et, dignissim varius mi. Nam porta interdum metus, eu sollicitudin erat ullamcorper sed. Aliquam erat volutpat.
</p>
<p>
Proin eget odio ultrices, sagittis sem ac, dictum nisl. Aenean bibendum id augue sodales lacinia. Morbi vehicula tincidunt tortor ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam elementum sem at dignissim hendrerit. Aenean dignissim neque urna, quis placerat mi viverra ut. Sed ultrices diam nec risus scelerisque, et consectetur sem laoreet. Suspendisse vitae odio purus. Aenean consectetur lacus vitae massa malesuada, sed interdum enim malesuada. Nulla pellentesque nunc ac dui condimentum interdum.
</p></div>
```