# Sticky header code not working with IE 11

Tags: javascript

The sticky header code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630548/sticky-header-slides-down-on-scrolling-up/41693042#41693042) working well with any browser but internet explorer 11. My question is: why this solution not working with IE 11?

**EDIT:** There is no answer to my question in topic to which i refer.

```
$(function(){   
var cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop();
var header_yuksekligi = $('.top').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {
var kaydirma_cubugu = $(document).scrollTop();

if (kaydirma_cubugu > header_yuksekligi){$('.top').addClass('gizle');} 
else {$('.top').removeClass('gizle');}

if (kaydirma_cubugu > cubuk_seviye){$('.top').removeClass('sabit');} 
else {$('.top').addClass('sabit');}

if (kaydirma_cubugu == 0) $('.top').removeClass('sabit');

cubuk_seviye = $(document).scrollTop(); 
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky header slides down on scrolling up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630548/sticky-header-slides-down-on-scrolling-up)

Comment: did you try check your console does it have any error(s)?

Comment: yes i did - no errors. if i watch page source (HTML) of my working site through IE11 developer tool while scrolling down, i see that class sabit activates already on scrolling down, but it should only then scrolling up.

Comment: I guess problem is with scrollTop, it may not work in IE